# Add device via wso2 emm

Tags: wso2-iot

I have installed wso2 Entreprise Mobility Manager.
Now, i want to add new device but mdm tab is not displayed from url:
 https://localhost:9443/emm/console/dashboard

Is there any configurations to do?
Can you tell me How to add devices?

Also, i want to know why i m rederect to localhost when i login from emm url wthit ip address?
so i can not access from remote device (computer or smartphone) to emm, is there any configuration that i forgotten or any thing i made wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Goto EMM device management from the console and click on 'Enroll Device'. You can first test it with and Android device. There you will get a link to enroll. Access that link from your device and download the Android agent and follow these guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/End-user+Registering+an+Android-powered+Device

for your second question you need to change /repository/conf/sso-idp-config.xml and change all localhost values to your ip address

Comment: thanks for reply
I followed the described steps but when i click on th download agent button on my android device i got :
(https://************:9763/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk)  web page not found
"************": is the ip adress of the server where the app wso2 turn on
Is there another xml config file to edit?

Answer (score 0):

i followed your steps described by Chatura Dilan but when i click on Download Agent on my android device i got https://******:9763/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk web page not found

"******" is the ip adress where the app turns on
Is there another xml config file that i should edit?